# Convert model list into json format

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, list

When I execute this I get a the result. But I want to convert the result into another formate.

```
public List<Data> getData() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("In getData dao************");
session=sessionFactory.openSession();
tx=session.beginTransaction();
List<Data> blist=session.createCriteria(>.class).list();
System.out.println("datalist dao************"+blist);
tx.commit();
session.close();
return blist;
}
```

Data.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_genere")
public class Data implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="dataid")
private String DataId;

@Column(name="dataname")
private String DataName;

public String getDataId() {
return DataId;
}

public void setDataId(String dataId) {
 DataId = dataId;
}

public String getDataName() {
  return DataName;
}

public void setDataName(String dataName) {
DataName = dataName;
}
```

I get the result as [`com.pack.web.model.Data@1233c96, com.pack.web.model.Data@5ec471]`. But I need to store the result in a file as json formate. that is like

```
{
"datalist":
{

"dataname1","dataname2","dataname3"
}
}
```

How can i convert it into this formate.

Comment: see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) example, how you can convert object to json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(datalist);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `jackson object mapper` you can do this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public String convertListArrayToJson(List<Object> objectList) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
// declaring string type final json array
String finalJsonArray = null;

// declaring the output stream for binding the data into the data
// variable
final OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// writing the data to the json format using the mapper
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(out, objectList);
// converting the output to the byte data
final byte[] data = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) out).toByteArray();

// converting the byte data of json to the string and storing it to
// the final json array
finalJsonArray = new String(data);


return finalJsonArray;
```

}